# An equivalent of Objective-C's "valueForKey" methodology in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Assume we have an Objective-C `NSArray` of instances of either the `Shoe` class or the `Computer` class. Both of these classes have the method `age`.

Objective-C would allow you to obtain the ages of all the shoes and computers in one simple statement like this:

```
NSArray *agesOfShoesAndComputers = [ourArray valueForKey:@"age"];
```

Does C++ have any similar methodology that can be applied to, say, vectors, or will stuff like this necessarily always be somewhat more cumbersome in C++?

Comment: You could achieve similar results using higher order functions in C++, but most people will just write a loop in this situation. I don't know Objective-C very well, so your example seems a bit strange to me. In C++, to have `Shoe`s and `Computer`s both in the same array, they'd both have to be subclasses of `AClassThatHasAge`

Comment: Can we first ask why you want to put two unrelated types into the same container in C++? There's probably a more idiomatic way to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `std::vector<T>` is *statically* typed. That is, you need to know whether it contains shoes, or computers, at compile time.

So, the short answer is that it'll always be more cumbersome in C++ (static typing is really an optimization, so this is the price we pay for performance).

---

If you want to use traditional runtime polymorphism, you need a common base class:

```
class MyBase
{
public:
    virtual ~MyBase();
    virtual int age() = 0;
};

class Shoe: public MyBase
{
public:
    virtual int age();
};
// same for Computer
```

now I can have

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> ourArray;
```

and

```
std::vector<int> ages(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> const &ourArray)
{
    std::vector<int> ages;
    std::transform(ourArray.begin(), ourArray.end(),
                   std::back_inserter<int>(ages),
                   [](std::unique_ptr<MyBase> const& elem) { return elem->age(); }
                  );
    return ages;
}
```

The call to `elem->age()` here relies on the common interface defined by `MyBase`, but dispatches to the derived class implementations (`Shoe::age()` and `Computer::age()` respectively).

It's less flexible than the Objective C version, because your common interface, inheritance etc. are all still statically defined.

Note that if this is a simple property, you *could* just skip the virtual method call entirely and put it in `MyBase` instead. Shoes and Computers will still need to inherit from this class, but they can just set the property value in the base class.

---

You may be able to use compile-time polymorphism instead, ie, templates. This is in some ways more similar to the Objective C approach, because it works for *any* type that supports the expected method, irrespective of inheritance relationships.

```
template <typename T> // T could be Shoe, Computer or anything else
std::vector<int> ages(std::vector<T> const &ourArray)
{
    std::vector<int> ages;
    std::transform(ourArray.begin(), ourArray.end(),
                   std::back_inserter<int>(ages),
                   [](T const& elem) { return elem.age(); }
                  );
    return ages;
}
```

the mechanism is completely different though - you still have *statically* distinct call sites with *either* `vector<Shoe>` *or* `vector<Computer>` or whatever, and never the twain shall meet.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is somewhat less dynamic, but what you're looking for is generally `transform`:

```
vector<unique_ptr<BaseClassForShoeAndComputer>> ourArray;
vector<int> agesOfShoesAndComputers;

transform(ourArray.begin(), ourArray.end(),
          back_inserter(agesOfShoesAndComputers),
          [](unique_ptr<BaseClassForShoeAndComputer>& s) { return s->age(); });
```

However, you can't really have unrelated objects inside a single container (well, you can, but it's another thing to use them); you *can* however, use templates (unfortunately, not with lambdas) to achieve static duck typing (for use with any type with an "age" method).

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler does not support `lambdas` you can use `<functional>` (but c++ 11 in any case)

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v;

std::vector<int> ages;
std::transform(v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               std::back_inserter(ages),
               std::bind(&Base::getAge, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Where `Base` is base class for `Shoe` and `Computer`

You can also use templates to get ages from any type that supports `getAge()` function.

```
template <typename InputIterator>
static std::vector<int> getAges(InputIterator start, InputIterator finish)
{
    typedef typename InputIterator::value_type T;

    std::vector<int> ages;
    std::transform(start,
                   finish,
                   std::back_inserter(ages),
                   std::bind(&T::getAge, std::placeholders::_1));
    return ages;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base> v;
    std::vector<int> ages = getAges(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Comment: And what about the `Computers`?